# Using `set -e` in a script prevents ((var++)) increment in bash

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
a=0
echo $a
((a++))
echo $a
```

returns only 0, yet remove the `set -e` and it returns 0 and then 1, why does ((a++)) return a non-zero status?

Comment: Use `((++var))` instead.

Comment: This is covered in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem using Ubuntu 16.04 and bash 4.3.11(1). Whether or not I include `set -e`, it produces both 0 and 1 as expected, no errors, no intermittent operations produce non-zero exit codes that could trip up `set -e`.

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted the shell code from the post in a file called `test.sh`, which I run with `bash test.sh`, either with or without the line containing `set -e`.

Comment: @ely, ...reading up, the behavior changed in bash 4.1. Which further emphasizes how nonportable and unpredictable `set -e` is -- anyone testing their code on 4.1 may not realize that their script is prone to exiting on 4.0 or prior, or on other POSIX-family shells without that exception.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree and regardless of whatever might be going on for me running the example locally, your answer is the right one. Using the `trap` pattern is better for error catching. Another, less satisfying option in this case could be to assign the result of `((a++))` to a throwaway variable.

Comment: @ely, `ERR` traps are unfortunately just as bad; they follow the same rules, and thus have the same caveats, as `set -e`. Manual error handling, [good static checking](http://shellcheck.net/) and careful human code review is the best practice here.

Comment: What tools do you use for this sort of thing? I used the `trap` approach with good success in a past project where we needed some very complex Makefiles that controlled complex interaction with Docker containers, so that we needed very special failure handling when e.g. running `make test` or `make install-data` sorts of commands. The `set -e` approach was used in some small helper scripts, but was too limiting otherwise. I'm very interested to know about more modern or better ways though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following three facts, taken in combination:

- `(( a++ ))` is a postincrement -- its return value depends on the value from *before* the increment takes place.
- In a numeric context, a zero value is falsey.
- `set -e` instructs the shell to exit if any unchecked command has a false exit status.

Thus, prior to bash 4.1 making an explicit exception for the case (preventing `set -e` from activating based on the exit status of an arithmetic expression), a numeric context whose contents evaluate to 0 will cause the shell to exit.

For the specific case at hand, you can work around the issue by using a preincrement -- `(( ++a ))` -- instead.

---

This is one of the [many respects](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) in which behavior of `set -e` is unintuitive and fault-prone (in addition to being [widely incompatible across shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/)). Its use is thus rightly controversial.

Answer (score 0):

Duffy explains the 'why' very well.  After some searching I was also looking at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/706683

And after considering the performance, I will be using this form in the future:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
a=0
echo $a
((++a))
echo $a
```

and I'll probably avoid set -e and instead test return values when needed.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of `declare -i` -- it decreases the locality of your code, meaning someone has to have seen the `declare -i` to know that `a+=1` will change `1` to `2` rather than change `1` to `11`. Increasing the amount of context needed to understand code makes review harder, and human review is (IHMO) the best route to reliability.

Comment: it looks like preincrement is the runner up in time at `0m0.556s` so preincrement it is

Comment: If performance is a primary goal, you're using the wrong language (and the wrong runtime -- if you want a shell that's fast at math, use real David Korn ksh93 if you care about POSIX compliance, or zsh if you don't).